# base64 encoded column want to decode using a xampp server what

Tags: mysql, xampp

Base64 encoded column want to decode using a Xampp server what  query should i use to select whole column from  table and decode it using Base64 to plain text ??
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.6.1 or higher you can use the [FROM_BASE64()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_from-base64) function. You can write your query inside file like :

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT  testid, setno, qnid, FROM_BASE64(question) as question FROM `table_name`");
```

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT testid, setno, qnid, FROM_BASE64(question) as question FROM `table_name`
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  FROM_BASE64(question) as question FROM `table_name`
```

Just run this SQL query.